# Granular Gitlab Permissions

Tags: git, github, permissions, gitlab, repository

We've been working with access permissions on gitlab . The understanding we get there is that there is a hierarchy of permissions like Maintainer,Developer,Reporter and Guest .

What we want is,Let's say,
We have 2 Developers , Jon, Mike .

We want Granular permissions based on the repo's we assign the permission to .
So if there is a repo called ABRepo,
We would like Jon to have the permissions on the ABRepo but Jason and Mike shouldn't.
All three belong to the same group.

We tried creating the groups and assigned individual permission for Jon (Guest) and Mike(Maintainer) .
But this goes without saying that every repo we assign this group to , will have the main permission that is assigned to the user(ie. guest to Jon & maintainer to Mike ).
So Jon stays guest throughout the repo where we assigned the group permissions .

How do i fine tune the permissions in such a manner that everything is managed by the group and individual permissions are applied based on the repo ?

Comment: You tagged both github and gitlab. I think you don't need the github tag?

Comment: In GitLab, I think it's typical to have one repo per project. Therefore the groups for each project can have different users in them. [More info here.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html)